# Get the size of checkbox

Tags: c++, winapi, checkbox

I am using a custom draw to change the text and background color of a *themed checkbox*.

In order to position text properly I need the dimensions of the check box. The below picture illustrates what I mean:

[image]

Browsing through StackOverflow archive I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164868/how-to-get-size-of-check-and-gap-in-check-box) but it got me confused. I just do not know which answer is the solution to my problem. Internet did not help either.

Comment: Seeing as the text is a single line, and the checkbox is square, you could just use its height like so: `VectorType(height, height)`.

Comment: @OMGtechy: That thought occurred me as well. Still, height of the text might be bigger than the size of the actual check box sometimes...

Comment: You should probably custom draw the entire control

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I am trying to do that according to one of your answers to a similar topic. If I create checkbox without text and call `DrawThemeParentBackground` in `CDDS_PREERASE` returning `return CDRF_NOTIFYITEMDRAW` the background is transparent. Furthermore, after I use `DrawText()` I am able to change text color ( and background if I want ) to the desired one. Being inexperienced, and since custom drawn button examples are scarce, I could use a code example, or at least some instructions. If necessary, I could post my code. Thank you for trying to help. Best regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function that you need, as I understand it is [`GetThemePartSize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759759.aspx). You need to supply `BP_CHECKBOX` for the part, and whichever of the [states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773210.aspx) is appropriate.

Comment: I had the same idea in mind, but I do not know how to determine which state to pass as the parameter. The only idea I have is to somehow use [`BM_GETSTATE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775988%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message. Then I should probably use `DrawThemeBackground` and `DrawText`. Thank you. Upvoted for now, I will officially accept after I successfully implement custom draw. Best regards.

Comment: Yes, you do need to know the state of the checkbox. If you draw it all, and you should, then you'll already need to be dealing with that.

Comment: I apologize for my previous answer, this question is about getting dimensions of a check box. Your post answers it. My problems stated in previous comments are of different nature and deserve a separate question. Accepted officially and upvoted. Thank you for your help. Best regards.

Answer (score 4):

```
function GetCheckBoxSize(AWnd: HWND): TSize;
var
  Theme: HTHEME;
  Bitmap: HBITMAP;
  BitmapSize: Winapi.Windows.TBitmap;
  State: DWORD;
  StateID: DWORD;
begin
  Result.cx := 0;
  Result.cy := 0;

  if IsWindowsXPOrLater and IsThemeActive and IsAppThemed then
    begin
      Theme := GetWindowTheme(AWnd);
      if Theme <> 0 then
        begin
          State := SendMessage(AWnd, BM_GETSTATE, 0, 0);
          if State and BST_CHECKED <> 0 then StateID := CBS_CHECKEDNORMAL
                                        else StateID := CBS_UNCHECKEDNORMAL;
          if GetThemePartSize(Theme, 0, BP_CHECKBOX, StateID, nil, TS_TRUE, Result) = S_OK then
            Exit;
        end;
    end;

  Bitmap := LoadBitmap(0, PChar(OBM_CHECKBOXES));
  if Bitmap <> 0 then
    try
      if GetObject(Bitmap, SizeOf(BitmapSize), @BitmapSize) = SizeOf(BitmapSize) then
        begin
          Result.cx := BitmapSize.bmWidth div 4;
          Result.cy := BitmapSize.bmHeight div 3;
        end;
    finally
      DeleteObject(Bitmap);
    end;
end;
```