# CheckBox disabled - disable only check box, not label

Tags: windows, checkbox, label, disabled-control, isenabled

I am using CheckBox in my Winforms application and it is showing to a user if some functionality is set or is not set. If the functionality is curretly running the CheckBox is flashing (label is changing color from black to grey in 1 second interval). But in some case I do not want allow the user to set on/off the functionality - in this case I disable the CheckBox. But this disable check box including its label and if the functionality is running, label is not flashing.

My question is if I can disable only check box - not its label. If the label is not disabled it can flash...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of ways you could solve this. In order of ascending difficulty:

#### 1. CheckBox.AutoCheck property

Setting `CheckBox.AutoCheck = false;` when you want to "disable" the checkbox will at prevent the user from being able to toggle it, however it will still appear to be enabled.

#### 2. Custom control

Implement your own custom checkbox control using a `CheckBox` with `CheckBox.Text = "";` and a separate `Label` control. When required, simply disable the `CheckBox` but not the `Label`.

#### 3. Override OnPaint

Create a control that is derived from `CheckBox` and override the `OnPaint` method. You can then draw the label part in whatever colour you like. The tricky part is getting the size and position of the box and the label parts which vary depending on OS version, theme, and accessibility settings. Methods for getting this information are explored in the following answers:

i. [Get the size of checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22689311/get-the-size-of-checkbox)

ii. [How to get size of check and gap in check box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164868/how-to-get-size-of-check-and-gap-in-check-box)

Comment: I want to CheckBox looks like it is disabled so solution 1 is not suitable for me. Solution 3 seems to be too complicated for such a small thing... I think that custom control is the best way. Thanks!