# MFC CheckBox - retrieve accurate square size

Tags: windows, winapi, checkbox, mfc, win32gui

The problem has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164868/how-to-get-size-of-check-and-gap-in-check-box), but people settled for an inaccurate solution. I'm using a `CButton` class with a `BS_AUTOCHECKBOX` flag. Is there a precise way to determine the size of the square with a black border (which holds the checkmark) on Windows/MFC? And also the gap between this square and text?

[image]

I realized, the gap can be calculated like this (`scale_factor` depends on the client's current screen DPI - 100%dpi, scale_factor==1; 150%dpi, scale_factor==1.5, etc.)

```
std::ceil(3 * scale_factor)
```

I need my solution to return the true size based on the client's screen resolution/DPI settings. Windows creates this square 13x13px on 100% DPI, 16x16px on 125% DPI, but 20x20px on both 150% and 175% DPI! Therefore, it's impossible to just multiply 13 with the `scale_factor`.

This code

```
int x = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXMENUCHECK);
int y = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYMENUCHECK);
```

returns 15px on 100% DPI, 19px on 125% DPI, and if I subtract

```
int xInner = GetSystemMetrics( SM_CXEDGE );
int yInner = GetSystemMetrics( SM_CYEDGE );
```

which returns 2px (on every DPI setting (???) ), I get my 13px on 100% dpi, but 17px on 125% DPI (it should be 16) and the error only gets bigger with higher DPIs. The problem is that the `SM_CXMENUCHECK` doesn't represent the standard `CButton` checkbox.

I'd like to avoid custom drawing. Is there any way to do this with pixel-precision (if not, what's the best possible solution you came up with)? Many thanks in advance.

EDIT:
Just to clarify, I need a function (or some algorithm) that will return 13px on 100% scaling, 16px on 125%, 20px on 150% AND 175% (and for any other possible scalings as well). That means I need a true size of the checkbox (which is drawn by Windows based on the resolution that is currently set on the client's screen).

Comment: Side question: Does it have to be a button? What about a standard checkbox which can also map to a click event.

Comment: There are some answers here worth investigating about themes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22689311/get-the-size-of-checkbox

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22695333/2287576

Comment: I don't know how to create a "standard checkbox" in MFC in another way than by creating CButton with a checkbox flag. Those topics look promising, thank you for that! I'll try it.

Comment: You can directly drag a checkbox from the resource editor.

Comment: I need to create the controls dynamically from the code. Anyway, the question has been answered, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`GetThemePartSize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/win32/api/uxtheme/nf-uxtheme-getthemepartsize?redirectedfrom=MSDN) function.

And some code :

```
HTHEME hTheme = ::OpenThemeData(hwnd, L"button");
SIZE szCheckBox;
HRESULT hr = GetThemePartSize(hTheme, NULL, BP_CHECKBOX, CBS_UNCHECKEDNORMAL, NULL, TS_TRUE, &szCheckBox);
```

Edit:

Answer related: [Determine checkbox square size [MFC]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/341472/determine-checkbox-square-size-mfc.html?childToView=342246#comment-342246)

Comment: I linked to that code in my comment to his question. 

Comment: @mrdecompilator Hi, does the answer solve your issue? Please feel free to let me know if you have any issue and also accept it if it does help.

Comment: Yes it does, I'm also attaching the link to the answer that gives the correct size of the gap - https://stackoverflow.com/a/59376905/13566062

Answer (score 1):

What about using [`GetSystemMetricsForDpi`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getsystemmetricsfordpi) ?

To quote:

> Retrieves the specified system metric or system configuration setting taking into account a provided DPI.
>
> This function returns the same result as `GetSystemMetrics` but scales it according to an arbitrary DPI you provide if appropriate.

So:

```
int x = GetSystemMetricsForDpi(SM_CXMENUCHECK, dpi);
int y = GetSystemMetricsForDpi(SM_CYMENUCHECK, dpi);

int xInner = GetSystemMetricsForDpi(SM_CXEDGE, dpi);
int yInner = GetSystemMetricsForDpi(SM_CYEDGE, dpi);
```

These methods and others are documented ([High DPI Desktop Application Development on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/hidpi/high-dpi-desktop-application-development-on-windows?redirectedfrom=MSDN#per-monitor-dpi-scaling-support-by-ui-framework--technology)) as the correct way to handle DPI issues and that article states:

> Also, in the case of Win32 programming, many Win32 APIs do not have any DPI or display context so they will only return values relative to the System DPI. It can be useful to grep through your code to look for some of these APIs and replace them with DPI-aware variants.

It even shows an example:

```
#define INITIALX_96DPI 50 
#define INITIALY_96DPI 50 
#define INITIALWIDTH_96DPI 100 
#define INITIALHEIGHT_96DPI 50 
 
 
// DPI scale the position and size of the button control 
void UpdateButtonLayoutForDpi(HWND hWnd) 
{ 
    int iDpi = GetDpiForWindow(hWnd); 
    int dpiScaledX = MulDiv(INITIALX_96DPI, iDpi, 96); 
    int dpiScaledY = MulDiv(INITIALY_96DPI, iDpi, 96); 
    int dpiScaledWidth = MulDiv(INITIALWIDTH_96DPI, iDpi, 96); 
    int dpiScaledHeight = MulDiv(INITIALHEIGHT_96DPI, iDpi, 96); 
    SetWindowPos(hWnd, hWnd, dpiScaledX, dpiScaledY, dpiScaledWidth, dpiScaledHeight, SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOACTIVATE); 
}
```

*Please note that according to the documentation this function is only supported on Windows 10.*

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Please, check out the edit of the original post. I don't want to specify the DPI, I want a function to return the true size of the checkbox based on the currently set DPI on the client's screen.

Comment: But that is what it will do. It is clearly what MS has provided to do the job. You have multiple monitors and multiple DPI possibilities. You work out what DPI value you are using and pass it to the function. It will return the correct scale value. Which answers your question you asked.

Comment: Okay, so what parameters should I pass to that function, so that it returns 20px for the 150% DPI and again 20px when the DPI is set to 175%? I don't think this function returns the correct values for the standard checkbox because SM_CXMENUCHECK does not denote the standard checkbox like in the screenshot I attached. It's a checkmark in the menu which is a completely different element.

Comment: I am not in a position to test and debug myself. My suggestion is to review that Microsoft Article first and test see what results you get after trying with the method they use for working out the DPI etc. It may bring you back to the same place in which case it is more of a Visual Studio query which you should direct to Microsoft through the software system on the Help menu. But try first as they will only ask you for a sample project that they can test with.

Comment: I tried a test app and it seems that no matter what DPI value I pass that `GetSystemMetricsForDpi` still returns `15` and `2` respectively. Doesn't sound correct. I would ask Microsoft.

Comment: Well, for me the function works exactly as it should, at least for 96, 120, 144 DPI. I already mentioned the problem, this function as well as my original one work with the element you give it. In our case, it's SM_CXMENUCHECK, which is not the element I'm interested in. There has to be another way, thanks for your suggestion though.