# Determine the size of a checkbox at arbitrary dpi on windows 10

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, dpi

See here: [How to get size of check and gap in check box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164868/how-to-get-size-of-check-and-gap-in-check-box)

It does not seem to quite answer the question as it applies to DPI.

I have tried several methods, but none yield the results of actual drawn checkboxes at various scale choices in Windows 10. The closest is

```
12 * GetDeviceCaps (LOGPIXELSX) / 96 + 1
```

This yields 22 pixels @ 168 DPI, however, but Windows draws a 20 pixel checkbox.

Is there a reliable way to determine this?  Below is a grid of results I captured, with greens being those that match the "on screen" values.

[image]

Comment: Are you interested in the classic or themed control? It is probably possible for the themed control to have transparent areas.

Comment: Another method for your table is to load `OBM_CHECKBOXES` and divide width by 4 and height by 3.

Comment: The column "Measured on Screen" closely matches `GetThemePartSize` column with the result `13,16,20,20,26`, which can't be matched to any linear equation. It appears to be based on what resources Windows has. Just use `GetThemePartSize` or use `MulDiv(13, GetDeviceCaps(LOGPIXELSX), 96)` which gives the result `13,16,20,23,26`

Comment: OpenThemeDataForDpi/GetThemePartSize

Comment: @Anders: I am mostly interested in classic.  I just measured the ribbon checkboxes, and they are different too.  13, 16, 20, 23*, 26.  Once again, 175% zoom is the odd man out, but this time it matches better to GetThemePartSize

Comment: @BarmakShemirani thanks.  Curious why you would go with MulDiv(13 which is different for 3 of the sizes vs. 1.  My goal is to match the windows sizes exactly for theming purposes.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Thanks for the idea. It yields the same results as the last column.  However, that inspired me to check some windows dialogs, which have 22pixels @ 168dpi, albeit with blurry edges.  So it seems CButton class in MFC is doing something a bit different at 175% zoom.  If you add that as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Actually, I suggested using `GetThemePartSize` which is off by no more than one pixel for each row. The others methods are off by 2 pixels or more for some rows. I am not really sure how you measure the pixels, so this is opinion based. I just mentioned the `MulDiv` method because it's same as `GetThemePartSize` except at 175%

Comment: @BarmakShemirani I referred to the second part of your answer.  Instead of using 13x, 12x+1 yields closer results. I agree about GetThemePartSize.